# How do I transfer a list of genres in SQL to a seperate database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sorting

I have in one database rough 2,000 movies with genres store like this:

```
MOVIE \ ID \ Genre
Avatar \ 1  \ action ^ adventure ^ scifi
matrix \ 2  \ action ^ scifi
```

and I was trying to make a system that would sort by genre, and when I researched it I found that I needed a table that would connect the two. (see this question: [MySQL select genres problem. (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423893/mysql-select-genres-problem-php))

So I know how to implement this, I just dont know how I could transfer the genres into a seperate table.

The only way I could come up with is to go row by row and grab the genre column and explode the text, get the array and test for different genres, but that seemed too much of a hassle and difficult to do on 2k+ rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you will store bizarrely delimited strings in your database to begin with...

Comment: "2K+ rows" doesn't sound too much for a modern database and/or programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you quote in your question seems to have nailed the database strutcure you require. So really it is about replicating this. 
Firstly I would create the `Genre` table. Again much like in the reference quoted the following structure will suffice.

```
+------------+---------+
|    id      |   genre |
+------------+---------+
|    1       | action  |
+------------+---------+
|    2       |  drama  |
+------------+---------+
```

and so on. Once you have created the genre table. You will need to create your movie_genre table where the genres will be stored. So for example

```
+----------+-----------+---------+
|  id      |movie_id   |genre_id |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

The following structure. Again like the reference quoted.

Once you have the database structure ready, the next thing would be to create a simple switch function. For example

```
public function returnGenId($genre)
{
   switch($genre)
   {
      case "action":
      return 1;
      break;
      case "drama"
      return 2;
      break;
   }
 }
```

Obviously the return will match with the id of the genre in the genre table.

You can now get everything from your database by doing

```
 SELECT * from movies
```

Which should leave you with an array similar to this

```
array(
       [0]=>array(
                   [id]=>1
                   [movie]=>Avatar
                   [genre]=>action ^ adventure ^ scifi
                 )
     )
```

Once you have your data then just loop through, exploding the genre and creating your new array for example

```
foreach($results as $key=>$result)
{
   $eplosion = explode(' ^ ',$result['genre'];
   foreach($explosion as $exploded)
   {
      $genres[] = returnGenId($exploded); 
   }
   $data[$result['id']] = array('movie'=>$result['movie'],'genres'=>$genres);
}
```

This should leave with an array like so (as an example, depending on the switch statement)

```
array(
   [1]=>array(
               [movie]=>Avatar
               [genres]=>array(
                               [1]=>1
                               [2]=>3
                              )
              )
 )
```

Now you can loop through the data as put it into the relevant database

```
foreach($data as $key=>$film)
{
    foreach($film['genre'] as $dbGenre)
    {

    }
}
```

In the second foreach do a mysql insert into movie_genre using `$key` as the `movie_id` and then `$dbGenre` as the `genre_id`. By doing this one script you can sort your database tables out and structure them correctly. Although this can be a hassle. Once you have got it out of the way, things will be infinitely easier. Let me know how you get on

***Update***

I've run these kind of scripts on databases with a couple of hundred thousand rows, so I can't see an issue for a couple of thousand. But this also depends on the memory size set on your server.

Increasing your memory limit may be an idea if need be, see this link:

http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-memory-limit-ini_set

Another idea is to hash out the last foreach loop and do a print of the data ie

```
print_r($data);

/*
foreach($data as $key=>$film)
{
    foreach($film['genre'] as $dbGenre)
    {

    }
}
/*
```

Before executing the script add this as close to the very top (preferably the first line)

```
$start = time();
```

Then add this to the bottom. Again as close the to the bottom of the script.

```
$end = time();
$wait = $end – $start;
echo 'The script took ' . $wait . ' seconds to run';
```

This will show you the amount of time taken.

Always before messing with the database though, dump the database for safety. Maybe even clone it and run this on a test database for peace of mind.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. Now my only question is if I'm doing this on 2,000 rows, will the page timeout while all the loops are run?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a new table for genres first than you might use SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '^', 1) in your query to select genres DISTINCT and write it to your new DB table in a single query.(INSERT INTO .... (SELECT ...). Than all you need to do is relate your new table of genres to your movies table. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241492/mysql-select-first-element-of-a-comma-separated-list) is a link for SUBSTRING_INDEX.