# MySQL Convert Varying Columns to Rows

Tags: mysql

I have a large dataset that contains one line per person, and 25 criteria columns that may or may not be populated, like this sample:

```
SELECT * FROM Criteria_Input;

╔══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ Name     ║ Criteria1 ║ Criteria2 ║ Criteria3 ║ Criteria4 ║ Criteria5 ║ Criteria6 ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ Michael  ║           ║    Yes    ║           ║           ║    Yes    ║           ║
║ Brant    ║           ║           ║           ║           ║           ║    Yes    ║
║ Mary     ║    Yes    ║           ║           ║    Yes    ║           ║           ║
║ John     ║           ║           ║           ║           ║    Yes    ║           ║
║ Connie   ║           ║           ║    Yes    ║    Yes    ║           ║           ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

I need to convert this data into rows like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Criteria_Final;

╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ Name    ║ Criteria  ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ Michael ║ Criteria2 ║
║ Michael ║ Criteria5 ║
║ Brant   ║ Criteria6 ║
║ Mary    ║ Criteria1 ║
║ Mary    ║ Criteria4 ║
║ John    ║ Criteria5 ║
║ Connie  ║ Criteria3 ║
║ Connie  ║ Criteria4 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

or even better, something this:

```
SELECT * FROM Criteria_Final;

╔═════════╦══════════╗
║ Name    ║ Criteria ║
╠═════════╬══════════╣
║ Michael ║     2    ║
║ Michael ║     5    ║
║ Brant   ║     6    ║
║ Mary    ║     1    ║
║ Mary    ║     4    ║
║ John    ║     5    ║
║ Connie  ║     3    ║
║ Connie  ║     4    ║
╚═════════╩══════════╝
```

Is this kind of data transformation possible in MySQL? The reason I need to do this kind of conversion is that I will join the resulting table with another table on the criteria number.

Comment: This question may help you, It's slightly different though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797916/how-do-i-transfer-a-list-of-genres-in-sql-to-a-seperate-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try query with UNIONs -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT name, 1 AS criteria FROM cr WHERE LENGTH(Criteria1) > 0
    UNION
  SELECT name, 2 AS criteria FROM cr WHERE LENGTH(Criteria2) > 0
    UNION
  SELECT name, 3 AS criteria FROM cr WHERE LENGTH(Criteria3) > 0
    UNION
  SELECT name, 4 AS criteria FROM cr WHERE LENGTH(Criteria4) > 0
    UNION
  SELECT name, 5 AS criteria FROM cr WHERE LENGTH(Criteria5) > 0
    UNION
  SELECT name, 6 AS criteria FROM cr WHERE LENGTH(Criteria6) > 0
) t
ORDER BY name, criteria
```

Change WHERE condition to check NULL values if needed.

Comment: Thank you @Devart, big time; this is an elegant solution and I love it! I put my final working code below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, based upon the beautiful solution from @Devart. First, the creation of the input table:

```
CREATE TABLE Criteria_Input (
  Name   VARCHAR(10),
  Criteria1 VARCHAR(5),
  Criteria2 VARCHAR(5),
  Criteria3 VARCHAR(5),
  Criteria4 VARCHAR(5),
  Criteria5 VARCHAR(5),
  Criteria6 VARCHAR(5),
  Criteria7 VARCHAR(5),
  Criteria8 VARCHAR(5)
);
```

Next, the creation of the final table:

```
CREATE TABLE Criteria_Final (
  Name   VARCHAR(10),
  Criteria INT(2)
 );
```

Then the insertion of the sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Criteria_Input
    (`Name`, `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, `Criteria3`, `Criteria4`, `Criteria5`, `Criteria6`)
VALUES
    ('"Michael"', NULL, '"Yes"', NULL, NULL, '"Yes"', NULL),
    ('"Brant"', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '"Yes"'),
    ('"Mary"', '"Yes"', NULL, NULL, '"Yes"', NULL, NULL),
    ('"John"', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '"Yes"', NULL),
    ('"Connie"', NULL, NULL, '"Yes"', '"Yes"', NULL, NULL)
;
```

And finally, the code that converts the data:

```
INSERT INTO Criteria_Final
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT name, 1 AS Criteria FROM Criteria_Input WHERE Criteria1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION
  SELECT name, 2 AS Criteria FROM Criteria_Input WHERE Criteria2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION
  SELECT name, 3 AS Criteria FROM Criteria_Input WHERE Criteria3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION
  SELECT name, 4 AS Criteria FROM Criteria_Input WHERE Criteria4 IS NOT NULL
    UNION
  SELECT name, 5 AS Criteria FROM Criteria_Input WHERE Criteria5 IS NOT NULL
    UNION
  SELECT name, 6 AS Criteria FROM Criteria_Input WHERE Criteria6 IS NOT NULL
) Criteria_Input
ORDER BY Name, Criteria;
```

You can see this in operation on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45286/2/0).